# Show/hide content of active row

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

In a bootstrap+jquery web page I build tables with this structure:

```
<table class="table table-striped" id="mytable"
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Id1</td><td>Description1</td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="quantity1" id="quantity1" class="hidden form-control"  />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Id2</td><td>Description2</td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="quantity2" id="quantity2" class="hidden form-control"  />
            </td>
        </tr>       
        <!-- ...and so on -->
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I want to show the input quantityN only if the row is active and keep the rest hidden.

I have this javascript to activate/deactivate rows:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $( "#mytable tbody" ).on( "click", "tr", function() {
        $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
        // Here show/hide row inner input fields
    });
});
```

What should I do to hide/show inner 'input' for the active row? Not sure how to refer to it.
Something like $(this) > td > input ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not doing it in css? like

```
#mytable tbody tr input {
    display: none;
}
#mytable tbody tr.active input {
    display: inline;
}
```

Comment: The css approach is cleaner than the jquery way I was trying to find out. Works great!

Answer (score 1):

You could use css:

```
#mytable tbody tr input {
   visibility: hidden;
}

#mytable tbody tr.active input {
   visibility: visible;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to show/hide on each click of tr then check if on click it is active or not and show / hide its input?

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
        $( "#mytable tbody" ).on( "click", "tr", function() {
            if($(this).hasClass('active'))
            {
              $(this).removeClass('active');
              $(this).find('input').removeClass('active');
            }
            else
             {
             $(this).addClass('active');
             $(this).find('input').addClass('active');
            }
        });
});
```

Comment: This approach works great. But the css way others suggested looks cleaner to me. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Your code works great. Only add these lines to css.

```
   tr input{
      display:none;
    }
    tr.active input{
      display:block;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Can be implemented with your `jQuery` code also with slight addition.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $( "#mytable tbody" ).on( "click", "tr", function() {
        $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
        // Here show/hide row inner input fields
        $( "#mytable tbody tr td input" ).addClass('hidden');
        $(this).find('input').removeClass('hidden');

    });
});
```

Heres the link:https://jsfiddle.net/mkLw6331/3/

Answer (score 1):

Use this code can be work for you :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $( "#mytable tbody" ).on( "click", "tr", function() {
      $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
      $(this).find("input").toggle();
    }); });
```

And Good luck